# Capturing a javafx Change event with mockito throws an IllegalStateException

Tags: javafx-2, mockito

I want to test using mockito, that some events are triggered when a javafx ObservableList is modified.

I have tried to to it this way :

```
@Test
public void handleListChanged() throws Exception {
    // [given]
    ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ListChangeListener<String> listener = mock(ListChangeListener.class);
    list.addListener(listener);

    // [when]
    list.add("test");

    // [then]
    ArgumentCaptor<Change> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Change.class);
    verify(listener).onChanged(argument.capture());
    assertTrue(argument.getValue().wasAdded());
}
```

bu an `IllegalStateException` raises on the last line :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at com.sun.javafx.collections.NonIterableChange.checkState(NonIterableChange.java:101)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.NonIterableChange.getPermutation(NonIterableChange.java:81)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeListener$Change.wasPermutated(ListChangeListener.java:156)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeListener$Change.wasAdded(ListChangeListener.java:165)
at FXCollectionsTest.handleListChanged(FXCollectionsTest.java:28
```

The documentation of the [wasAdded()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html#wasAdded%28%29) method warns that an `IllegalArgumentException` could be thrown *"if this Change is in initial state"* but i don't understand it.

---

Why my code is not working ?

Is there a solution for testing this code using mockito ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call the `next` method first on the `Change` object before you can call any other method like `wasAdded`.

**Unit test**

```
assertTrue(argument.getValue().next());
assertTrue(argument.getValue().wasAdded());
```

**Documentation**

> public abstract boolean next()
>
> > Go to the next change. In initial state is invalid a require a call to next() before calling other methods. The first next() call will make this object represent the first change.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html#next%28%29)